# Jupyter notebook restart kernel with keyboard

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I program with my laptop, and having to use the touchpad is just the worst.  I `<Esc>, 0, 0` to 'restart the kernel' per the keyboard shortcuts docs, but that gives me a dialog... when I hit `<Return>`, it selects, apparently, the "don't restart the kernel, actually" option.  `<Tab>, <Return>` doesn't seem to work for selecting the 'restart' option in the dialog.

Please help me escape the evil clutches of my touchpad!

Answer (score 3):

If you upgrade to a newer version of the notebook, you can define your own keyboard shortcuts and so could set you own shortcut for the "restart kernel" command which does not prompt you. Editing keyboard shortcuts was introduced in 5.0, and can be done via `Help > Edit Keyboard Shortcuts`

If you cannot upgrade the notebook for whatever reason, then it may just be your browser. I tested it in both Chrome and Firefox and it auto-selects the Restart option for me, and I can switch between the two options using `Tab` and `Shift+Tab` and press `Enter` to select them.

Comment: "I tested it in both Chrome and Firefox and it auto-selects the Restart option for me, and I can switch between the two options using Tab and Shift+Tab and press Enter to select them."... huh... It may be related to the vim-bindings extension or some such.  I will investigate this.